# Find cell value in a column

Tags: excel, vba

Cell A3 has a LEFT formula that extracts first 3 characters of another cell with a dropdown.
Need VBA to search the result of A3 formula in column A, and select that cell.

Getting a Compile error:

> Object required on "strSearch =" in 3d line of below code.

```vb
    Sub findAA()
    
        Dim rng1 As Range
        Dim strSearch As String
        Set strSearch = Range(A3).Value
        Set rng1 = Range("A:A").Find(strSearch, , xlValues, xlWhole)
        If Not rng1 Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "Find has matched " & strSearch & vbNewLine & "corresponding cell is " & rng1.Offset(0, 1)
        Else
            MsgBox strSearch & " not found"
        End If
    
    End Sub
```

UPDATE: to avoid the range issue (see comments), I moved A3 to B4. Macro worked when run by itself, but does not work when using the Active X Control's Combo Box, which changes the value of now B4. The idea is that when Combo Box changes, it triggers change in B4, which should trigger the code to select the resulting cell in column A. Code now looks like this:

```vb
        Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
        If Target.Address = "B4" Then
            Dim rng1 As Range
            Dim strSearch As String
             strSearch = Range("b4").Value
            Set rng1 = Range("A:A").Find(strSearch, , xlValues, xlPart)
                If Not rng1 Is Nothing Then
                    rng1.Select
                End If
        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: Remove `Set` from `Set strSearch = Range(A3).Value`, and add quotes `"` around `A3`.

Comment: Thanks, @BigBen - that moved the code past it. But how do I now get it to select that cell, aside from getting rid of MsgBox lines in that code?

Comment: Do you mean `rng1.Select`?

Comment: @BigBen - that selects cell A3 itself, which is used to communicate the search term to the macro, whereas I need it to select the cell containing the result of that search.

Comment: Well you're looking in all of column A, so the search found cell A3.

Comment: @BigBen - sure, tried to lower that range, by setting it to "A9:A" in fourth line, but getting "Run-time error '1004': Method "Range' of object '_Global' failed"

Comment: `A9:A` is not a valid range reference (needs a closing row number).

Comment: @BigBen - changed it to "A9:A5000", getting "Run-time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set" on "rng1.Select" line

Comment: Then the `Find` did not find the value in A9:A5000. Do you have the `rng1.Select` within the `If Not rng1 Is Nothing Then`?

Comment: @BigBen - to avoid this range issue, I moved A3 to B4.  Macro worked when run by itself, but does not work when using the Active X Control's Combo Box, which changes the value of now B4. Code now looks like this:  `Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = "B4" Then
        Dim rng1 As Range
        Dim strSearch As String
         strSearch = Range("b4").Value
        Set rng1 = Range("A:A").Find(strSearch, , xlValues, xlPart)
            If Not rng1 Is Nothing Then
                rng1.Select
            End If
    End If
End Sub`

Comment: nothing seems to work on this site: like getting to the next line in comments, or pasting code to be formatted nice. what are they thinking.

Comment: @BigBen - thanks for bearing with my frustration. I edited the main question with an update at bottom.

Comment: I don't think the Combo Box changing B4 actually causes the `Worksheet_Change` event to fire, if I remember correctly. Use the Combo Box event handler instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what works for me now - Thanks, in part, to @BigBen:

This code calls the find macro upon change in ComboBox:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
Call findAA
End Sub
```

This is the working find code:

```
Sub findAA()

Dim rng1 As Range
Dim strSearch As String
 strSearch = Range("b4").Value
Set rng1 = Range("A:A").Find(strSearch, , xlValues, xlPart)
If Not rng1 Is Nothing Then
rng1.Select
End If
End Sub
```